# Why am I getting a syntax error when creating a function in python that takes in two argument to determine the kind of speeding ticket I will get?

Tags: python

You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write a function to return one of 3 possible results: "No ticket", "Small ticket", or "Big Ticket". If your speed is 60 or less, the result is "No Ticket". If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is "Small Ticket". If speed is 81 or more, the result is "Big Ticket". Unless it is your birthday - on your birthday, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

Here is the function I've created (in Jupyter Notebook) to solve the above problem:

```
    def caught_speeding (speed, is_birthday):
        if speed <= 60:
            print ('no ticket')
        elif speed >= 66 and speed <= 85 and is_birthday = 'Y':
            print ('small ticket')
        elif speed >= 61 and speed <= 80 and is_birthday = 'N': 
            print ('small ticket')
        elif speed >= 86 and is_birthday = 'Y':
            print ('big ticket')
        elif speed >= 81 and is_birthday = 'N':
            print ('big ticket')
        else:
            print ('null')
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

[[image: Error Screenshot[1]]

I don't get this error if I create the function with only the first argument.

Comment: It should be '==' to check for equality and not just one '='  which is an assignment operator. Additionally 'is_birthday' could be a boolean instead of a char.

Comment: @AhmadMoussa yes, that is it. Definitely not worth losing the two points that I did for this question.

Comment: No worries, just double check in the future before posting on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `==` for equal comparison, not `=`

See the document about Comparisons
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score -1):

`=` is assignment and `==` is comparison

```
is_birthday == "Y" or "N"
```